# Putty Stop responding after some time

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ssh, web-crawler, putty

I am using putty to connect to my aws instance and there i am running a php script that need to crawl more than 100k records.My problem is that when i am running that 100k records from php cli script then after some time ,say after 10-15 minutes it stops responding and got stuck.
I am sure it is not a connection error as when putty stops due to connection error it says "putty (INACTIVE)" and in my case this is not happening.

Comment: You probably lost the connexion. Is your internet connexion stable ?

Comment: yeah my connection is stable as i am using wired broadband connection

Comment: I'd say you should show us the code you use. Otherwise it is hard to make any useful suggestion.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that not involved the code because it's executed on the server and putty is just the tool he uses to make his ssh connexion.

Comment: code is pretty long, and it executing without no error for almost 10-15 minutes.
yes but i can share the ssh details as it is a testing server.

Comment: Look into enabling the "keep alive" settings in the Putty configuration. And look into using something like `screen` to enable your session to keep running if you temporarily disconnect.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the PuTTY client and under connection make sure you Enable TCP keepalives (as in the image) and you set non 0 value (usually 60) like this.

This will keep your connection alive when not active.[image]